# Delete file from specific model field when uploading a new version when Model has several file.fields without deleting everything Django

Tags: python, django, storage

my problem is regarding orphaned files and the fact that my model uses several file fields. I have a model for a user, which has a profile image field and a cv field. The user is able to update these fields which works fine but the old files remain. Now I've looked at various solutions online, created my own etc but its not working quite properly. The problem with my solution (see below) is that it deletes all old media files associated with that instance at that time even though I've only changed one value. Additionally, each of the fields have their own directory path so its not a case of recursive deletion due to sharing the same directory path. Its fine when I change both fields since both change and the previous files are deleted but often people only change one value so how do I fix this? I don't want to use django-cleanup for a variety of reasons.

**models.py**

```
def teacher_avatar_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'teachers/avatar/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.email.replace(" ", "_").lower(), filename)
def teacher_cv_directory_path(instance, filename):
    # file will be uploaded to MEDIA_ROOT/user_<id>/<filename>
    return 'teachers/cv/{0}/{1}'.format(instance.user.email.replace(" ", "_").lower(), filename)


#Teacher
class ProfileTeacher(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True, blank = False, null = False, verbose_name = 'Creation Date')
    user = models.OneToOneField(app_settings.USER_MODEL,blank=True, null=False)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length = 400, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'First Name')
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length = 400, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Surname')
    phone_number = models.CharField(max_length = 15, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name = 'Phone Number')
    cvv = models.FileField(upload_to=teacher_cv_directory_path, null=True, blank = True, verbose_name="CV")
    profile_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=teacher_avatar_directory_path,
                                      null = True,
                                      blank=True,
                                      default='/perfil.png',
                                      )



#-------Model image and files clean up ----------------------------------
@receiver(post_init, sender= ProfileTeacher)
def backup_image_and_cv_paths(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    instance._current_image_file = instance.profile_image
    instance._current_cvv_file = instance.cvv

@receiver(post_save, sender= ProfileTeacher)
def delete_old_image(sender, instance, **kwargs):
    if hasattr(instance, '_current_image_file'):
        if instance._current_image_file != instance.profile_image.path:
            instance._current_image_file.delete(save=False)   
    if hasattr(instance, '_current_cvv_file'):
        if instance._current_cvv_file != instance.cvv.path:
            instance._current_cvv_file.delete(save=False)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make custom save method for your Model. [Docs here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.from_db)

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
   field_1 = ...
   field_2 = ...  

   def save(self, *args, **kw):
      if self.id:

         # Check that instance that you are sending for update have files in it
         # Get corresponding file field(s) and manually remove old file(s) according to the path
         # Store new file(s) to the file field(s)
         # Update other fields if required

         super().save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: I already have a custom save and this isn't solving the deletion issues. Perhaps your answer needs more details.

Comment: @fmakawa You are using the same business logic that I've proposed? I mean it's realy hard to guess what you do without seeing it =) Please share your save method so everyone will have opportunity to help you.